# Dock in Lion FullScreen

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I would like to know if there is a way to have the dock always there when running an App fullscreen in lion?

Comment: I´m not sure if you´re aware of that, but by moving your cursor at the screen-edge your dock resides on and then pushing the cursor "into" the edge again, the Dock will pop out. Other than that Mouse gesture (and pressing cmd+alt+D) I´m not aware of another solution yet.

Comment: For posterity, I found this question while trying to figure out how to make the dock appear in fullscreen apps.  The answer to that related question is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107663/how-do-i-see-the-dock-in-a-fullscreen-window-in-os-x/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very unlikely that Apple will ever support this request officially, as it would go against their whole "full-screen" philosophy. However, it ought to be possible to create a SIMBL hack which achieves it.

If you do want the dock visible when using an app - perhaps the best solution is not to use fullscreen, but simply make the app window large by using the green traffic light button or dragging the edges.

Comment: This should've been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I think it was answered quite well.