# How do I see the dock in a fullscreen window in OS X?

Tags: macos, dock, fullscreen

I'm running Mac OS X Mavericks and I have several apps set up to use fullscreen mode.  There's no dock at the bottom of the screen, and it doesn't appear either when I scroll to the bottom of the screen like it normally does in non-fullscreen mode.

How can I reveal the dock when in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 30):

It appears that the trick is to move the cursor to the bottom of screen like I normally would, but KEEP MY FINGER ON THE TRACKPAD when I get there.  If you take your finger off of the trackpad, the dock won't appear, but if you keep it there then it will.

(There are other reports that moving the cursor to the bottom of the screen and then repeating the same action again can make the dock appear, but I had inconsistent results with that technique.)

Comment: I can't believe i didn't think in leaving the finger on the trackpad. Thank you so much, it was bothering me a lot.

Comment: Any tips for mouse? It's annoying as hell, that I have to keep moving my mouse down to get the dock.

Answer (score 10):

You can check this out yourself:

When you fast-move the cursor to where your Dock is hidden or when you pause right there and let the cursor hover. No Dock.

**Here’s the trick:**

You need to move the cursor very slowly. That’s all you need to do. If you move it too fast to the edge of your screen, the Dock won’t show up.

Comment: I think I'm with Simon on this one. When I tried the first answer above nothing happened. But then I tried the second. For the first time in months the sweet dock showed her face and the menu bar above. Move the cursor slowly.

Comment: Note that you can move fast to the bottom, then when already at the bottom, move down a little.

Answer (score 4):

After you reach the bottom of the screen with the mouse cursor, keep sliding your finger down in the trackpad.

Comment: This certainly works! Move your cursor to the bottom edge and KEEP SLIDING down on the macbook trackpad. I also tested with the magic trackpad and magic mouse. All work the same way!

I assume it also works in any direction. I tested it with the dock on the right and it works the same way. When you're on fullscreen mode, just move the cursor to the right edge and keep sliding your finger to the right. The dock is revealed :). Perfect! I learned something new today

Answer (score 1):

When you are in non-full screen mode the dock appears when you move cursor to bottom. But, in full screen apple developers probably didn't want you to be distracted when you take your cursor down(say to select a text at last line of the document), that's why you need to keep your cursor there and not move your finger from trackpad. In other words, dock is not a preference when in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

You go to Setting>Dock>Uncheck Auto hide dock

Answer (score 0):

The real trick is you have to think your dock is hidden 1 inch bottom of the full screen app's bottom part. Then you have to move your cursor more deep than you would usually do. I got 100% success with this trick.